# Can i deserialize xml directly into a List

Tags: c#, restsharp, xml-deserialization

this might be a silly noobish question, but please bear with me =)

In my program I receive a piece of xml something akin to this:

```
<markers>
        <marker id="35" name="Test1" address="anyway123" type="event"/>
        <marker id="370" name="Test2" address="" type="event"/>
        <marker id="251" name="Test3" address="somewhere 1337" type="com"/>
</markers>
```

What I want to know if there's a way to have a class, containing sort of something like this:

```
private int id;
private string name;
private string address;
private string type;

public int Id {
    get {
        return id;
    }
    set {
        id = value;
    }
}
public string Name {
    get {
        return name;
    }
    set {
        name = value;
    }
}
public string Address {
    get {
        return address;
    }
    set {
        address = value;
    }
}
public string Type {
    get {
        return type;
    }
    set {
        type = value;
    }
}
```

Lets call it "EventClass" and then simply go like:

Could I then simply go something like this:
List eventList =  "XMLStuff"

And if yes, what would XML stuff entail? xD

Regards,
-Logan =)

Comment: Yes, you can. And you know how the peace you're looking for is named: Deserializer.

Comment: Oh, I googled before hand (quite a bit) but I didn't come across that one, you're right, this is a dup. Is there any way I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard `XmlSerializer` if you're willing to make a few modifications to your class:

- XML is case-sensitive so you should use lower-case names for your properties (`id`, `name`, etc.
- create a containing class with an array of your data class
- Add the attribute `[XmlRoot("markers")]` to the containing class
- Add the attribute `[XmlElement("marker")]` to the array property

Something like this:

```
[XmlRoot("markers")]
public class EventList
{
    [XmlElement("marker")]
    public List<EventClass> EventClasses {get; set;}
}


public class EventClass
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string address {get; set;}
    public string type {get; set;}
}
```